# Are representables on the étale site on topological space sheaves?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, schemes

The gluing lemma says representables on the classical site on $\mathsf{Top}$ are sheaves. Basic scheme theory says the same is true for the small Zariski site of a scheme.

Are representables on the étale site on topological space sheaves? Why should one expect this to be the case for schemes?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is true; the point is that étale maps locally have continuous inverses.  An étale cover of a topological space $X$ is a space $Y$ together with a map $p:Y\to X$ which is surjective and a local homeomorphism.  To say representables are sheaves is to say that if $Z$ is a topological space and $f:Y\to Z$ is a continuous map such that $p(x)=p(y)$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$, then there is a unique continuous map $g:X\to Z$ such that $gp=f$.  Clearly there is a unique such map of sets $g$, so it suffices to check that this $g$ is continuous.

Fix a point $x\in X$.  Since $p$ is surjective, there is some $y\in Y$ such that $p(y)=x$.  Since $p$ is a local homeomorphism, there is an open neighborhood $U\subseteq Y$ of $y$ such that $p(U)$ is open in $X$ and $p$ restricts to a homeomorphism $p_U:U\to p(U)$.  For all $z\in p(U)$, we then have $g(z)=g(p(p_U^{-1}(z)))=f(p_U^{-1}(z))$.  Thus $g|_{p(U)}=f\circ p_U^{-1}$ and is hence continuous.  Thus $g$ is continuous in a neighborhood of any point of $X$, and hence continuous on $X$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any intuition for why this should also hold for schemes?

Comment: How does $p(x)=p(y)\implies f(x)=f(y)$ present the sheaf condition? I'm confused.

Comment: @popo The sheaf condition is that the sections over $X$ be the equalizer of the two maps from sections over $Y$ to those over $Y\times_X Y$, which is the space of pairs in $Y$ equalized by $p$.

Comment: Well, the rough intuition is that because it works for topological spaces (or perhaps more relevantly, complex analytic spaces), you might expect it to work for schemes too.  But I confess that I don't have a good algebraic intuition for why ring-homomorphism should satisfy étale descent.